# How to play a sound only at the first time false value after true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I have person data that contain dynamic boolean value. The value is generated automatically and can be true or false every time.

Webpage get the data every 5 seconds and render it. If the value on each person is false then the sound is played.

This is the code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Sound from './Mp3';

const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Peter',
    value: true
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'John',
    value: false
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    results: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
    // get data every 5 sec
    setInterval(this.getData, 5000);
  }

  getData = () => {
    // generate random value
    data[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    data[1].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;

    // set results state to data
    this.setState({ results: data });

    // condition if John or Peter value is false
    if (data.some(d => d.value === false)) {
      var audio = new Audio(Sound);
      // play a sound
      audio.play();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { results } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {results.map(item => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <div>
                Name: {item.name}
              </div>
              <div>
                Value: {item.value.toString()}
              </div>
              <br />
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8gecfb?embed=1&file=index.js)

With the code above, the sound is played every time if the value on each person is false.

How to play a sound only at the first time false value after true?

I mean, if the first rendered John value is false then play a sound and if 5 seconds later John value still false then don't play a sound after the value back to true and change to false again.

Results I expect :

```
// first rendered
Name: Peter
Value: true  

Name: John
Value: false  // play a sound

// second (5 seconds later)
Name: Peter
Value: true  

Name: John
Value: false  // don't play a sound

// third (10 seconds later)
Name: Peter
Value: true  

Name: John
Value: true  // don't play a sound

// fourth (15 seconds later)
Name: Peter
Value: true  

Name: John
Value: false  // play a sound

...
```

Comment: first case - John has a true value, but your requirement is to `With the code above, the sound is played every time if the value on each person is false. ` Could you explain that, please?

Comment: Mr. Asiniy, yes Peter has a true value and John has a false value, it will automatically generate random true or false every 5 seconds. So for the first rendered the sound just play for the John false value.

Comment: I'm sorry Mr. Asiniy, it looks different between my code data and data in result i expect. I already updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of each users's previous value outside of the getData function inside of another object, then compare the previous value with the new value inside of the some.

```
  state = {
    results: []
  }

  const previousResults = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData()
    // get data every 5 sec
    setInterval(this.getData, 5000);
  }

  getData = () => {
    // generate random value
    data[0].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    data[1].value = Math.random() >= 0.5;

    // set results state to data
    this.setState({ results: data });

    // condition if user value is false & previous result for user was not false
    if (data.some(d => (d.value === false) && (this.previousResults[d.id] !== false))) {
      var audio = new Audio(Sound);
      // play a sound
      audio.play();
    }

    data.forEach((item) => {
      this.previousResults[item.id] = item.value;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, can you please show me how to do that with my code?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Jdgower, i tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sort of "Circuit Breaker" which keeps track of its state, and whether it is enabled. Having tripped, it waits an amount of time before re-enabling itself.

The code below demonstrates the following

- switching from `true` to `false` executes the `action` callback
- continuing to pulse `false` does NOT repeat this action
- switching to `true` and then waiting a greater amount of time than the `timeout` before pulsing a new `false` again executes the `action` callback.

```js
function TFCircuitBreaker(timeout, action){
    this.state = null;
    this.enabled = true;
    
    this.valueChange = function(newValue){
        if(this.enabled){         
          if(this.state && !newValue){
              action();
              this.enabled = false;
              setTimeout( () => this.enabled = true,timeout);
          }
        }
        this.state = newValue;
    }
}

var cb = new TFCircuitBreaker(5000, () => console.log("Play sound"));
cb.valueChange(true);
cb.valueChange(false);
cb.valueChange(true);
cb.valueChange(false);

cb.valueChange(true);
setTimeout( () => cb.valueChange(false), 6000);
```

Ive also updated your demo with similar code which I think does what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kmfiij?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but i have no idea how to combine your code above with the demo code.

Comment: @Ras did you see the last line of my answer?

Comment: @Jamec I did not notice you last line, i'm sorry for that.
i try see your link above but seems it's different, i want to play a sound if the value is false, and on your link it sound played at true value. when i look, it seems not play a sound if the peter value change from true to false and john from false to true. i mean, i want to play a sound every person data changed from true to false.

Comment: @Ras if you cannot negate a boolean, there is no chance you're going to be able to write this code!

Comment: @Jamec i'm sorry for make you annoyed. With your link above i can't see you updated code. Can you please show the code?

Comment: @Jamec you say, there is no chance if i cannot negate a boolean. If i change the boolean value to string ex: 'true' or 'false' is it possible to play a sound every person data changed from string 'true' to 'false'? i'm sorry, i really confused to make this code works. Thank you.

Comment: Then you're in a world of pain. I think youve misunderstood my comment. Negating a boolean means turning true to false. That is all that is needed to "fix" the problem with my code you pointed out.

Comment: Mr. Jamiec, my expected result like this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g6gvtd?embed=1&file=index.js). but it have an issue must manually create a state, setState & audio on each person data if data increases.